# Admob Banner ad showing blank? Why?

Tags: android, admob

I have tried so many times before but getting the same result always. Ads shows blank as my title says. I don't know what's getting error with me? I learn from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/). Below is my code and screen shot:

[image: why is this blank ad?]

This is my activity_main.xml, where I implemented ad at footer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/img_boy"
    android:background="@drawable/big_img_boy" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/dog_male"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@drawable/one" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/dog_female"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@drawable/two" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/img_girl"
    android:background="@drawable/original_girl" />
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2679xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx42"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In MainActivity I call this inside onCreate

```
    AdView adView= (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Here's my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <activity android:name=".Splash_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".Settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".About_Developer"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Did I lose/forgot any steps? I am using all other fragment and activity_main as container, when I go to fragment this  banner automatically shows at top instead of showing at bottom. Below is the screen shot.

[image: Fragment]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="3dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
app:cardElevation="3dp"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ff9901"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Call them in ManActivity when button is click like below code:-

```
case R.id.img_boy:
            Recycler rc = new Recycler();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =     fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, rc);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
```

And below is how I inflated my View

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, container, false);
    rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    nameCollection = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.boy);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();
    return view;
```

Below is logcat

```
 08-31 17:23:24.208 25652-25724/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 10, size: 0
 08-31 17:24:43.512 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
 08-31 17:24:43.929 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames I/Ads: Starting ad request.
 08-31 17:24:43.932 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("0F7B337499FCAAA05252B09EFC57223C") to get test ads on this device.
 08-31 17:24:44.994 2526-2526/? I/Ads: Received log message: <Google:HTML> You are using version 8.5 of the Google Play Services Ads SDK. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest features and bug fixes. See [link][4] for instructions on how to get the latest version of Google Play services.
 08-31 17:24:45.267 2526-5326/? W/Ads: Error while connecting to ad server: Connection closed by peer
 08-31 17:24:45.272 15331-15352/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
 08-31 17:24:45.278 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
 08-31 17:24:45.278 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 2
 08-31 17:25:45.337 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames I/Ads: Starting ad request.
 08-31 17:25:45.339 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("0F7B337499FCAAA05252B09EFC57223C") to get test ads on this device.
 08-31 17:25:46.775 2526-5324/? W/Ads: Error while connecting to ad server: Connection closed by peer
 08-31 17:25:46.777 15331-15352/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
 08-31 17:25:46.778 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
 08-31 17:25:46.779 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 2
 08-31 17:26:46.835 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames I/Ads: Starting ad request.
 08-31 17:26:46.836 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("0F7B337499FCAAA05252B09EFC57223C") to get test ads on this device.
 08-31 17:26:47.185 2526-2526/? I/Ads: Received log message: <Google:HTML> You are using version 8.5 of the Google Play Services Ads SDK. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest features and bug fixes. See [link][4] for instructions on how to get the latest version of Google Play services.
 08-31 17:26:47.642 2526-5322/? W/Ads: Error while connecting to ad server: Connection closed by peer
 08-31 17:26:47.645 15331-15352/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
 08-31 17:26:47.646 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
 08-31 17:26:47.648 15331-15331/queendevelopers.com.nepalibabiesnames W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 2
```

Comment: may be your admob id is not valid

Comment: Please share logs as well.. usually logs displays error which causing admob not to display ads. also XXX out your admob ID adUnitId. you do't want to display to public

Comment: @Amod Why, is there anything bad we could do with it, except using it and making him money?

Comment: Wait? Do I send all logcat or filter any keyword or error only? please specify

Comment: logs related to tag Ads/Admob tag:^(?!.*(Ads)).*$

Comment: I filter this and nothing found. I don't understand how to do this. Anyway, I posted the logcat its so big,

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt why to share important information to all? People with wrong intentions can easily use this ID, create enough fraudulent clicks and get ID locked? Its better be safe then sorry

Comment: @Queendevelopers filter log with "Ads" or add debug point where you have loaded ads and see logcat if you see any errors. Also check if you have latest version of GooglePlayServices  installed

Comment: @Queendevelopers - There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2 . error code 2 appears if date time is incorrect. Just set autodate correcting on your device. Another test is to change internet ( switch from WIfi - > data or vice versa )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Queendevelopers - There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2 . error code 2 appears if date time is incorrect.

1. Just set autodate correcting on your device. Another test is to change internet ( switch from WIfi - > data or vice versa )
2. Update Google Play Services on device in question

Also update to latest Google Play Library in your project.

Comment: Thank you Amod Gokhale for your suggestion, Due to some reason, I cannot switch to mobile data, I run into emulator and ad showing perfectly fine.. But can you fix the next problem i ask? the second screenshot i.e. fragment, the ad is showing at top, I hope you don't mine editing your answer!! Thank you so much Amod

Comment: sure. please post layout xml for fragment control having issue

Comment: I didn't implement ad in all those fragment, as I said earlier, activity_main is the fragment_container, I call fragment using fragmentTransaction.add(...), anyway I will post xml above.. please see my edited question

Comment: not sure if i understood code but try adding this to your adview control android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: No, Its not working, Anyway thanks for the help!! I Appreciate your effort!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your MainActivity

```
RelativeLayout adContainer = (RelativeLayout)
                findViewById(R.id.adMobView);

        AdView mAdView = new AdView(this);
        mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
        adContainer.addView(mAdView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Add this in your main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/adMobView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Also remember that banner ads requires (width,height 320X50).
Implement the following in buid.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Get your google-services.json from firebase console. Add this file into your app directory.